# How to hide ContextMenus with no visible items?

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

I have several ContextMenus with items defined as such:

```
<ContextMenu>
    <MenuItem Header="Item 1" Command="{Binding Item1Command}"/>
    <MenuItem Header="Item 2" Command="{Binding Item2Command}"/>
    <MenuItem Header="Item 3" Command="{Binding Item3Command}"/>
</ContextMenu>
```

The `Command` bindings have `CanExecute` set so that when it's false, the `MenuItem` has `IsEnabled=false`. This goes on with a trigger that sets `Visibility=Collapsed` when `IsEnabled=false` and the opposite happens as well.  The problem I'm running into is if all `MenuItem`s are disabled, the `ContextMenu` still shows up as a small blank rectangle.  I have a lot of `ContextMenu`s, so what would be the most modular way to implement this?

Comment: You can bind the Visibliity of the ContextMenu to the Items and write a converter if there are no visible items.

Comment: As far as I know, bindings are within the DataContext, which would be my ViewModel, but my menu items are explicitly defined in the view.  I understand the converter part, but how do you accomplish the first half with making only changes to the View?  Not to mention, I'm not certain if the Items collection triggers NotifyPropertyChanged for the converter to actually work depending on the triggered visibility of MenuItems.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing a different workaround instead of hiding the visibility of the ContextMenu. It seems like it may be less efficient since it checks for all FrameworkElement ContextMenus, but it is working:

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(FrameworkElement), ContextMenuOpeningEvent,
    new RoutedEventHandler(OnContextMenuOpening));

private void OnContextMenuOpening(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var control = (sender as FrameworkElement);
    var menu = control == null ? null : control.ContextMenu;
    if (menu != null)
    {
        var items = menu.Items.Cast<MenuItem>();
        if (items.All(i => i.Visibility != Visibility.Visible))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

If there is a better way to do this without having code behind, for the parent control nonetheless, I'm open to alternative solutions.

Comment: I just tried with StaticResource and the result is what you need. if you want I can paste the code here for you to check it out. It's not straight forward solution but it should give you a good idea about how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of xaml that will get you started with "Conditional" ContextMenu.
**Please note:** this is only starting point

```
<ListView>
         <ListView.Resources>
             <ContextMenu x:Key="initial">
                 <Menu>
                     <MenuItem Header="First Option"></MenuItem>
                 </Menu>
             </ContextMenu>
             <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                 <Style.Triggers>
                     <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Text}" Value="1">
                         <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource initial}" />
                     </DataTrigger>
                 </Style.Triggers>
                 <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource initial}"/>
             </Style>
         </ListView.Resources>
         <ListViewItem>1</ListViewItem>
         <ListViewItem>2</ListViewItem>
     </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to solve that is via attached property, but it looks quite acceptable to me. First define a class with property:

```
public class ContextMenuExtension
{
    public static bool GetHideOnEmpty(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(HideOnEmptyProperty);
    }

    public static void SetHideOnEmpty(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(HideOnEmptyProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HideOnEmptyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HideOnEmpty", typeof(bool), typeof(ContextMenuExtension), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, HideOnEmptyChanged));

    private static void HideOnEmptyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var contextMenu = d as ContextMenu;

        if (contextMenu == null)
            return;

        contextMenu.Loaded += ContextMenu_Loaded;
    }

    private static void ContextMenu_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var contextMenu = sender as ContextMenu;
        var hideOnEmpty = GetHideOnEmpty(contextMenu);

        HideContextMenu(contextMenu, hideOnEmpty);
    }

    //This is where we check if all the items are not visible
    private static void HideContextMenu(ContextMenu contextMenu, bool val)
    {
        //First, we have to know if the HideOnEmpty property is set to true. 
        if (val)
        {
            //Check if the contextMenu is either null or empty
            if (contextMenu.Items == null || contextMenu.Items.Count < 1)
                contextMenu.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; //Hide the contextMenu
            else
            {
                bool hide = true;
                //Check if all the items are not visible.  
                foreach (MenuItem i in contextMenu.Items)
                {
                    if (i.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
                    {
                        hide = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                //If one or more items above is visible we won't hide the contextMenu.
                if (!hide)
                    contextMenu.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                else
                    contextMenu.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in XAML with your ContextMenu add a namespace to class above and do following:

```
<ContextMenu cc:ContextMenuExtension.HideOnEmpty="True">
   <MenuItem Header="Delete" Command="<delete_command>" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
</ContextMenu>
```

Every time user right clicks to see the menu, it will trigger "HideContextMenu" method from "ContextMenuExtension" class and if no items or all of them are not Visible - hide entire ContextMenu.